# Custom Event in Rebol

Tags: rebol

C#, Java even Javascript can create custom event. As far as I can read in an obscure single post (http://www.mail-archive.com/rebol-list@rebol.com/msg14321.html) that wasn't possible for Rebol 2, what about rebol 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes and no.

R3 can handle any events comming out of the OS, but only a few event names are registered within the core.  this means adding new "classes" of events cannot be done, though you can map any OS event to one of these event types.